# Reuse of expression containing SqlFunctions.DatePart

Tags: entity-framework, expression

I have the following LINQ-to-Entities query, for retrieving records which match the date part of a given date (`dte`):

```
Dim qry = entities.Works.Where(Function(w) w.JobID = RecordID And
  SqlFunctions.DatePart("y", w.FromDate) = SqlFunctions.DatePart("y", dte) And
  SqlFunctions.DatePart("m", w.FromDate) = SqlFunctions.DatePart("m", dte) And 
  SqlFunctions.DatePart("d", w.FromDate) = SqlFunctions.DatePart("d", dte))
```

I would like to reuse this expression, by first writing something like this:

```
Public SqlDateEquals As System.Linq.Expressions
    .Expression(Of Func(Of DateTime, DateTime, Boolean)) = Function(dte1, dte2)
     SqlFunctions.DatePart("y", dte1) = SqlFunctions.DatePart("y", dte2) And 
     SqlFunctions.DatePart("m", dte1) = SqlFunctions.DatePart("m", dte2) And 
     SqlFunctions.DatePart("d", dte1) = SqlFunctions.DatePart("d", dte2)
```

Then, within other queries:

```
Dim qry = entities.Works.Where(Function(w) w.JobID = 
    RecordID And SqlDateEquals(w.FromDate, dte))
```

My understanding is that LINQ-to-Entities parses the expression passed into `.Where`, and it should be able to recognize `SqlFunctions.DatePart` as a part of the expression as well. Therefore, expressions which contain `SqlFunctions.DatePart` should still be parseable to their equivalent SQL.

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Your approach looks sound, are you having problem getting the code provided to compile?

Comment: It's not compiling - `Class 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of DateTime, DateTime, Boolean))' cannot be indexed because it has no default property`

Comment: This doesn't compile because in VB.NET expressions cannot be invoked with parentheses. VB.NET therefore interperts the parentheses as calls to the indexer. However, explicitly calling `Invoke` is not an option, because `Invoke` cannot be translated to SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [EntityFunctions.TruncateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596.aspx):

```
Dim datePart = dte.Date
Dim qry = entities.Works.Where(Function(w) w.JobID = RecordID And _
    TruncateTime(w.FromDate) = datePart)
```

Note: I realize that this doesn't answer the question, but it does solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are seeing is not related to `SqlFunctions.DatePart`; rather, it is because you cannot combine your two expressions in the way you're attempting.

**Composing expressions** like this is actually not as straightforward as you might expect.  The lambda expression syntax is a shorthand that doesn't support composing expressions; you have to use the static methods on `Expression` instead.

Fortunately, **there is an easier way** for your case:

**Update:** Added sample code for doing this the long way too, using static 'builder' methods of `Expression`.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.Linq.Expressions
Imports System.Data.Objects.SqlClient
Imports System.Reflection

Class Entity
    <Key> Public Property Key As Integer
    Public Property P As String
End Class

Class Context
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Property Entities As DbSet(Of Entity)

End Class

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim expression1 As Expression(Of Func(Of Entity, Boolean)) = Function(e) e.P > "m"

        Dim ctx As Context = New Context()
        Dim query = From e In ctx.Entities
                    Where e.P < "p"
                    Select e

        ' Example 1.  The easy way: chaining two Where clauses together.
        ' This works because q.Where(A AND B) is the same as q.Where(A).Where(B)
        Dim q2 = query.Where(expression1)

        Console.WriteLine(q2.ToString())

       ' Now the harder method.
        Dim expression2 As Expression(Of Func(Of Entity, Boolean)) = Function(e) e.P < "p"

        ' Reproduce the above using static builder methods.
        ' Get an expression for our single parameter.
        Dim parameter As ParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(GetType(Entity))

        ' Get an expression for accessing its P property.
        Dim pProperty = Expression.Property(parameter, "P")

        ' Get a MethodInfo for the string comparison method.
        Dim compareMethod As MethodInfo = (From m In GetType(String).GetMethods()
                                           Where m.Name = "Compare" AndAlso m.GetParameters().Count() = 2 AndAlso m.ReturnType = GetType(Integer)
                                           Select m).First()

        ' Generate our combined lambda.
        Dim combinedExpression = CType(
            Expression.Lambda(
                Expression.Or(
                    Expression.GreaterThan(Expression.Call(compareMethod, pProperty, Expression.Constant("p")), Expression.Constant(0)),
                    Expression.LessThan(Expression.Call(compareMethod, pProperty, Expression.Constant("m")), Expression.Constant(0))),
                parameter), 
            Expression(Of Func(Of Entity, Boolean)))

        Dim combinedQuery = ctx.Entities.Where(combinedExpression)

        Console.WriteLine(combinedQuery.ToString())

        Console.Read()
    End Sub

End Module
```

The first expression in the above example works on the basis that `.Where(A AND B)` is logically the same as `.Where(A).Where(B)`.  As the above sample code demonstrates, EF correctly generates nice SQL code for this.

The second expression output by the above code is *much* more complicated.  It shows how you can build up expressions in code.  Here, because we so an `OR` operation, we couldn't use the trick of chaining `Where()` calls.

For a wonderful discussion of the problem and its solutions, see [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates.aspx).